# Cardinal of the Special Orthogonal Group $SO_n\left(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}\right)$

Tags: matrices, cardinals, orthogonal-matrices

Let $SO_n(R)$ be the group of matrices with coefficients in a ring $R$ whose determinant is equal to $1$.

I remembered an old question asked at an oral exam :

$$\text{What is the order of the group }SO_n(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}) \ ?$$

Is there a way to count them ? I don't see a way to solve this question

Comment: Small clarification: $\mathbb{K}$ is often used specifically for fields, but the field of order $2^n$ is not 'just' $\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$. Presumably you mean the ring?

Comment: Yes, the ring sorry

Comment: I actually spoke slightly incorrectly here — the notion of 'determinant equal to 1' makes sense for an arbitrary ring, but $SO(n,F)$ is AFAICT almost exclusively looked at for fields $F$, so it may well be that the question is about the finite field $F_{2^n}$ (in which case the answer is apparently Complicated). Do you have any more details on the question?

Comment: The answer in the case of field turns out to be easier, and it is $2^{n\binom{n}{2}}$, while in the ring case seems pretty hard even for small $n$'s (look at the sphere equation with three or four variables below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us count the cardinality $c_n(m) $ of $C_n(m):= SO_m(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}) $ by induction on $m$. The base case is easy, since evidently $c_n(1) = 1$. Now consider the action of $C_n(m)$ on  $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}) ^m$ for $m\ge 2$.

The key observation is that the stabilizer of $e_1$ is precisely $C_n(m-1) $. Indeed, you have an orthogonal matrix with first column $(1 \ 0 \ldots \ 0) $, so all the other columns must start with zero and the determinant of the $(m-1) \times (m-1) $ matrix left in the bottom-right must be one.

The orbit of $e_1$ under $SO_m$ are all the vectors
$$(x_1, \ldots, x_m) \in (\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}) ^m \ : x_1^2+ \ldots + x_m^2 = 1 $$
but up to a square root of 1 in $\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$. Let us denote this set by $X_2(n)$. Indeed, $O_m(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z}) = SO_m(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z}) \cdot X_2(n) $, so that the orbit under $O_m$ will be the orbit under $SO_m$ times the orbit under scalar multiplication of $X_2(n) $. I don't have any effective ideas at the moment to compute $O_n(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}) e_1$, so let's call it $K_{n, m}$. The other involved quantity - $X_2(n) $, is easy to compute: recall that the multiplicative group of $ \mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) ^{n-2} $ for $n\ge 2$, so that the elements of order 2 are 4 if $n\ge 3$, and $n$ if $n\le 2$.

Since the orbit and the stabilizer have product equal to the cardinality of the group, we have that

$$ c_n(m) = c_n(m-1) \cdot K_{n, m} /x_2(n) $$

This implies that

$$ c_n(m) =\left (  \prod_{r=2}^m K_{n, r} \right ) / (x_2(n) ) ^{m-1}$$

**A special case**. In the case of $n=1$ the sphere equation is particularly simple, as it would be in any field of characteristics 2. Indeed the square commutes with the sum and we have

$$ (x_1+\ldots+x_m) ^2 = 1$$

which implies that the sum must be an element of $X_2(1) =\{1\}$. If you choose the first $m-1$ elements as you wish in 0,1, you can choose in the right way $x_m$ in a unique way so that the equation holds true. This shows that $K_{n, m}= 2^{m-1} x_2(1) $, so that

$$ c_1(m) =  \prod_{r=2}^m K_{1, r} / (x_2(1) ) ^{m-1} = \prod_{r=2}^m 2^{r-1} = \boxed{ 2^{\binom{m}{2} }}$$

Edit. The last observation makes me suspect that the original question was in the field of characteristics 2 $F_{2^n}$, for which the last result hold but with exponent $n\binom{m}{2} $ (the argument is pretty the same!).